# WCF: FaultContracts and exception hierarchies

Tags: c#, wcf, faultcontract

My system consists of two sites, communicating between themselves using WCF. Occasionally, exceptions are thrown when one site invokes operations on its peer, and I'm trying to decide what's the best way to use WCF's FaultContracts in such cases.

In past projects, I was used to creating a non-trivial exception hierarchy, e.g.:

```
BaseSystemException
    CustomerServiceException
        CustomerNotFoundException
        BadCustomerNameException
        CustomerAlreadyExistsException
        ...
    OrderServiceException
        OrderNotFoundException
        OrderAlreadyExistsException
        ...
```

However, implementing such a hierarchy quickly becomes tiresome in WCF because I have to specify each concrete exception type in its own FaultContract. Now, since both services are part of the same system, there is no issue of leaking information/sensitive callstacks/etc. I want B to provide as much information as possible in its exceptions, so that A can react accordingly. I should note that in practice, many of these exceptions are dealt with in the same way (failing the operation and notifying the user), but when designing my exception scheme, I don't want to assume identical handling for all exceptions.

Can anyone suggest an approach that doesn't require a FaultContract for each exception type? Is there an easier way? This is an internal interface, after all. Am I being too idealistic in wanting to use an exception hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into throwing a [FaultException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultexception.aspx) instead? This doesn't break your WCF service so your client can handle the exception.

EDIT:

As you want to keep the type of exception I don't think there is a way out of using FaultContracts. The only thing I can suggest is to consolidate some of your exceptions.

e.g `CustomerNotFoundException` and `BadCustomerNameException` could become `FailedToFetchCustomerException` and then the message can convey the reason why.

Comment: A simple FaultException doesn't convey much information - it pretty much flattens any exception hierarchy into a single exception. If I want to throw FaultException<T>, then I will need to define FaultContract(T) for all T, no?

Comment: From your question I thought that you didn't really care what the exception was as you handle them all the same way (failing the operation and notifying the user)

Comment: Well, my wording was a bit confusing there. What I meant was that in practice, most exceptions are dealt with in the same manner, but I still want the exception to convey as much information as possible. I'll update my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That's what I feared - that I would have to re-design my exception hierarchy specifically for WCF. I was hoping to avoid this, though, and somehow automagically have WCF support an arbitrary exception hierarchy (again, for an internal service).

Comment: Its the nature of the beast I'm afraid. The client side needs to know what a valid response is from the server. Can I suggest a lot of copying and pasting..? ;-)

Comment: I was hoping there would be some WCF hook I can use to circumvent the "map non-FaultContract exception to non-generic FaultException" behavior. Oh well.

Comment: No worries. If it helps the first place I'd look would be at serialisation and setting known types. There might be a way in there. Maybe you could have a poke around with Reflector.